# why error "accessing build database disk I/O error"?

Tags: oclint

When I use `Xcode10.2.1` run `Oclint` target,there is a error as below:

> Build system information :-1: error: accessing build database
>   "/Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-axffsqylozkazhaxuzxqhztnaywu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db":
>   disk I/O error

Comment: my script is :    xcodebuild -workspace $myworkspace -scheme $myscheme clean & xcodebuild -workspace $myworkspace -scheme $myscheme | xcpretty

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964543/xcode11-gm-error-accessing-build-database-disk-i-o-error